# Groovy - No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.isArray()

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I'm writing a program that would arm/disarm my home and everything executes properly, but I keep on getting the following error message at the end of execution.

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.isArray() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: isEmpty(), every()

My code is

```
def disarm() {
    log.debug "During disarming. SessionID: ${state.token}"
    if(state.token) {

        def paramsDisarm = [
            uri: "URL",
            body: [SessionID: state.token, LocationID: location, DeviceID: deviceID, UserCode: usercode]
            ]
            httpPost(paramsDisarm) { responseDisarm ->
            log.debug "Code is ${responseDisarm.data.ResultCode}"
            log.debug "Message: ${responseDisarm.data.ResultData}"  
            sendPush("Home is now Disarmed")
            }
       log.debug "Is this getting executed?"
       logout()
    }
    else
    {
    log.debug "Smart Things is not logged in. Need to login"
        login()
        disarm()
    }

}
```

My logout call is

```
def logout() {
    log.debug "During logout - ${state.token}"
    def paramsLogout = [
            uri: "URL",
            body: [SessionID: state.token]
            ]
            httpPost(paramsLogout) { responseLogout ->
            log.debug "Smart Things has successfully logged out"
        }  
}
```

Looking at the console log, I see everything is executed quite well. Here is the console log.

```
8:58:41 PM: error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren.isArray() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: isEmpty(), every()
8:58:41 PM: debug Smart Things has successfully logged out
8:58:40 PM: debug During logout - 65103122-1915-49C2-A021-015871AD7C93
8:58:40 PM: debug Is this getting executed?
8:58:40 PM: debug Message: Session Initiated. Poll for command state update
8:58:40 PM: debug Code is 4500
8:58:36 PM: debug During disarming. 65103122-1915-49C2-A021-015871AD7C93
8:58:36 PM: debug Smart Things has logged In. SessionID: '65103122-1915-49C2-A021-015871AD7C93'
8:58:32 PM: debug Smart Things is not logged in. Need to login
8:58:32 PM: debug During disarming. SessionID: null
8:58:32 PM: debug Mode is set to Home, Performing Disarm
```

My code runs fine and does what it should, but the error message still bugs me.

Comment: the full stacktrace of the exception would help

Comment: kinda new to this. I was doing some google around it to use it. But not sure how can I do it. Any pointers to get a stacktrace